# Where does the mariadb logs exists

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

I am using mariadb and I to investigate some issue I wanted to check the logs. To my surprise, log file is not generated for mariadb.

I suspect this cannot be the case so I am doubting my search skills.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'log_error'
    -> ;
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_error     |       |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have added the entry in my.cnf still above field is coming to be empty.

```
[root@cslcodev11-oem ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
!includedir /etc/mysqld/conf.d
datadir=/mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql_tmp
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
### TRT-3229 #####
sync_binlog=1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_support_xa = 1
myisam_repair_threads = 2
myisam_recover_options = FORCE
###################
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
table_open_cache=256
max_heap_table_size=256M
### TRT-4685 ###
max_connections=500
################
innodb_log_file_size = 512M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[root@cslcodev11-oem ~]#
```

So, I want to know do we have any default location where these logs are getting generated, if the path cannot be read from config files.

### Update:

After some investigation, I found this information,

*Reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/error-log/*

---

**Activating the Error Log**

The error log is active by default. The log-error=filename option determines where the output will be written. If no file name is specified, the log will be written to host-name.err. If no absolute path is specified, the file will be written to the data directory (determined by the value of the datadir system variable).

*On Unix systems, if the --log-error option is not used, the errors are written to stderr (usually, the command line).*

*On Windows, if the --console option is specified, and --log-error is not used, the errors are written to the console. If --log-error is present, --console is ignored.*

So now I understand that due to some reason the configuration **log_error** in my.cnf is not considered.  So as per the suggestion, on Unix system, if --log-error is not used, logs are redirected to stdout.

---

BUT, I am starting the service using `service mysqld start` command so I want to know what all options are used by default when we start the service using `service mysql start`? ESP, is --log-error used?

Comment: Have you actually restarted the server or just put it in the my.cnf and assumed it would work instantly?

Comment: This is the provisioned setup so all the configuration is applied before starting mariadb.

Comment: Check out `ls -l /var/log/mysql*`

Comment: NO it's not there

Answer (score 0):

If you're presently using a 2023 version of MariaDB, and if you already activated the MariaDB logs, one of those commands below might show the log location. Which command works depends on your operating system:

```
mariadbd --print-defaults
```

or

```
mariadb --print-defaults
```

or

```
my_print_defaults --mysqld | grep log-error
```

"If the above don't help, check also if your system is set to [write to syslog](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/#configuring-mariadb-to-write-the-error-log-to-syslog), in which case you need to use **journalctl** to access it."

Source at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/

Answer (score 0):

it's underscore instead of minus:
`log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log` should be `log_error=/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log`